# OpenCV C++ - Video saved using VideoWritter cannot be opened

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

So I am trying to edit all the frames from input video and than save them to the output. The saved video appears and has the proper filesize but can't open and the imshow inside the while doesn't show the frames at all (only a blank window). I've tried numerous codecs (H264,MJPG,MPEG,MPV4,XVID,CVID) and non of them make it work. What could be the problem? Also, the first function is for converting RGB to YUV and returning the gray channel, while the second one works with HPF and LPF. These functions work on individual images so I don't think they are the problem.

```
#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>

#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;


Mat KonverzijaRGB2YUV(Mat ulazniFrejm){
    
    int width = ulazniFrejm.cols;
    int height = ulazniFrejm.rows;

    Mat konvertovan(height, width, CV_8UC3, Scalar(0,0,0));

    for(int i=0; i<width; i++){
        for(int j=0; j<height; j++){
        
            double R = ulazniFrejm.at<Vec3b>(j,i).val[0];
            double G = ulazniFrejm.at<Vec3b>(j,i).val[1];
            double B = ulazniFrejm.at<Vec3b>(j,i).val[2];

            double Y = 0.299*R + 0.587*G + 0.114*B;
            double U = 0.436*(B-Y) / (1-0.114);
            double V = 0.615*(R-Y) / (1-0.299);

            konvertovan.at<Vec3b>(j,i).val[0] = Y;
            konvertovan.at<Vec3b>(j,i).val[1] = U;
            konvertovan.at<Vec3b>(j,i).val[2] = V;
        }
    }

    Mat Ykanal[3];
    split (konvertovan, Ykanal);

    Mat YkanalRGB;
    cvtColor(Ykanal[0], YkanalRGB, CV_GRAY2RGB);

    return YkanalRGB;
}

Mat Izostravanje(Mat ulazniFrejm){

    Mat izostrena;

    float valLaplas[] = 
    { 0.,-1.,0.,
     -1.,4.,-1.,
      0.,-1.,0. };

    Mat kernelLaplas(Size(3,3), CV_32FC1, valLaplas);
    Mat Laplas;
    filter2D(ulazniFrejm, Laplas, -1, kernelLaplas);

    convertScaleAbs(Laplas, Laplas);

    Mat Gaus;
    GaussianBlur(ulazniFrejm, Gaus, Size(3,3), 0, 0);

    addWeighted(Laplas, 1.4, Gaus, 1.0, 0, izostrena);

    return izostrena;

}
int main(int argc, char** argv){

    VideoCapture ulazniVideo("esmeralda.mp4");

    int brojFrejmova = static_cast<int>(ulazniVideo.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT));

    if(!ulazniVideo.isOpened()){
    
        cout << "Video se ne moze otvoriti" << endl;
    }

    waitKey(1000);

    Size frameSize = Size((int)ulazniVideo.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), (int)ulazniVideo.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));
    int fps = ulazniVideo.get(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
    int ex = -1;

    VideoWriter izlazniVideo;
    izlazniVideo.open("esmeralda.mp4", ex, fps, frameSize, true);

    int brojac = 0;

    while(true){
    
        Mat frame;
        ulazniVideo >> frame;

        Mat konvertovanFrejm;
        konvertovanFrejm = KonverzijaRGB2YUV(frame);

        Mat izostrenFrejm;
        izostrenFrejm = Izostravanje(konvertovanFrejm);
        
        if(frame.empty()){
            break;
        }

        izlazniVideo << frame;
        brojac++;

        namedWindow("Video", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        imshow("Video", izostrenFrejm);

        int waitKey(1000/fps);
    }

    waitKey(0);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: where's your `VideoWriter::release` call? please follow documentation and tutorials.

Comment: you will need a way to close the recording in a clean way and call the release method

Comment: @Micka Very stupid of me to forget the release call, but it still doesn't make it work.

Comment: `int waitKey(1000/fps);` -- that's not calling `waitKey`, that defines an integer variable of that name. Since that means you never call `waitKey` in the loop, and since that runs the message loop, none of the GUI stuff works.